# How to Move a Sprite at a Constant Speed With Move(to

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've been trying to figure out how to use moveTo with a constant moving speed for a while now. Here's an image of an example of what I want to do:
[image]

Here's code that I have attempted to use which gives me 2 errors:

```
    var destination = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var distance = sqrt(pow((destination.x - SKSpriteNode.position.x), 2.0) + pow((destination.y - SKSpriteNode.position.y), 2.0));
    var moveDuration = 0.001 * distance;
    var move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(destination.x,destination.y), duration: moveDuration)
    enemy.run(move)
```

How could I solve these errors or how could I make a new and improved SKAction?

Comment: Get the speed from one equation so that you can get the duration of the other equation with the former.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: You'll need to replace `SKSpriteNode` with an instance of `SKSpriteNode`

Comment: Sorry, how would I do that? Can you give examples as well